# Did anyone bring up Dumbledore's past rejections to Fudge?

Tags: harry-potter

So, in *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*, Fudge was going about believing that Dumbledore wanted his job. With Dumbledore frequently reminding him of the laws, **did he or anyone else mention he already turned down the job of Minister of Magic a few times**. (3 times, I think). In fact, these rejections were partially why Fudge got the job in the first place.

Comment: What, you mean just to get up his nose even further?

Comment: Why do you think it would have mattered? Fudge was paranoid, and paranoid people don't listen to reason.

Comment: Reminding Fudge that he was second choice is bound to make him like you. And just because Dumbledore turned down it down once doesn’t mean he doesn’t want it now – indeed, maybe he even meant for Fudge to screw it up first, so he could swoop in and pick up the job later.

Answer (score 1):

Fudge was paranoid, so it wouldn't a-mattered to him whether or not Dumbuldore wanted his job, and it would've made him mad to hear that he was the second choice; he wouldn't a-wanted to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, there are no references made explicitly to Fudge being told this information, although, as others have suggested in comments it is likely that:

1) He probably was aware of it as it seemed to be a pretty well-known fact.

2) It would not have been sufficient to get Fudge to change his views on Dumbledore or Voldemort.